# Generate filename with php Random functionality

Tags: php, random

I would like to randomize the choice of html to use in a side panel 
I need a php call to populate a variable with a randomized file name.

The file name is Righname_x.html , where x is the random number (should be between 1-5)

How would I go about generating the filename to store in the variable?

Answer (score 1):

```
$filename = 'rightname_' . mt_rand(1,5) . '.html';
```

Should do the trick. Using mt_rand() instead of rand() for better randomness

Comment: I'm asking for help because I don't know php, just need this one call. How do I concatenate the file name with that function?

Comment: $filename is the variable that contains the filename. I can only guess beyond used variable in the current code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $min=1;
  $max=5;
  $x =rand($min,$max);
  $filename = 'Righname_'.$x.'.html';
?>
```